# Leaflet event on Shiny works only once

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I'm developping a Shiny app including a leaflet map. On the Shiny app, I've one panel, that displays a button. If this button is clicked, this panel is reorganized and the map is replaced by other plots. (It might not be the cleanest thing to do but I need to reorganize the panel, I don't want two different panels). If the user clicks again, the map is back and the other plots disappear. This part works very well.

I also want to trigger an event if the user clicks on one marker on the map.

The problem is the following : if the user clicks before updating the page using the button, everything works. But if she uses the button first, the click on the map is not detected even if the popups on the map are well displayed.

Here is a reproducible example. A click on a marker is supposed to print the click in the console.

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(dplyr)
library(datasets)




ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("map")
  )

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
values <- reactiveValues(reorganize = FALSE)
  
output$map = renderUI( if (values$reorganize){
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 4, actionButton("reorganize_button", "Reorganize")
    )
  )
  } else {fluidRow(
    column(width = 4, actionButton("reorganize_button", "Reorganize"), leafletOutput("leafletmap"))
  )}
  )

observeEvent(input$reorganize_button, {
  values$reorganize = !values$reorganize
})


  output$leafletmap <- renderLeaflet({
    quakes$region <- factor(quakes$long >= 175, labels = c("Ouest", "Est"))
    quake_couleur <- colorFactor(c("blue", "red"), domain = c("Est", "Ouest"))
    carte_quake <- leaflet()
    carte_quake <- addTiles(carte_quake)
    quake_couleur <- colorFactor(c("blue", "red"), domain = c("Est", "Ouest"))
    carte_quake <- addCircleMarkers(
      map = carte_quake,
      lng = quakes$long,
      lat = quakes$lat,
      color = quake_couleur(quakes$region),
      popup = paste("Latitude:", quakes$lat, ", longitude:", quakes$long),
      label = paste("Magnitude", quakes$mag),
      radius = quakes$depth/100 
    )
    carte_quake <- addProviderTiles(
      map = carte_quake,
      provider = providers$Stamen.Watercolor
    )
    return(carte_quake)
  })
  

  observeEvent(input$leafletmap_marker_click, {
    click <- input$leafletmap_marker_click
    print(click)})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I've honestly no idea of what causes the problem.

Before I put the button, the map worked well.

Does anyone have an idea on how to fix this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution : putting a `req(!values$reorganize)` inside the `renderLeaflet` function does the job.

Thanks

```
output$leafletmap <- renderLeaflet({
    req(!values$reorganize)
    quakes$region <- factor(quakes$long >= 175, labels = c("Ouest", "Est"))
...
})
```